# Удаление div#app со страниц при работе Vue.js и Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Возникло непонимание процесса работы Laravel и VUE.js из коробки.

1. Устанавливаю Laravel (5.8.32) через Composer
2. Настраиваю соединение с Mysql (.env)
3. Выполняю команду `php artisan make:auth` чтобы получить шаблоны
4. Запускаю миграции с заполнением `php artisan migrate --seed`
5. Выполняю `npm install`, но пересборку сразу не выполняю
6. Перехожу на адрес `/login` или `/register`

И вот при загрузке страницы /login или /register на мгновение появляется форма Входа или Регистрации в полном оформлении с верхним меню (которое из коробки) и после остается только пустой экран.

При просмотре исходного кода страницы весь код оформления из шаблона есть, но при инспектировании кода в инструментах разработчика отсутствует `<div id="app"></div>` вместо него `<!---->` ну и соответсвенно нет содержимого на странице.

Если в `app.js` вызвать `alert('Test');` и пересобрать проект, то сообщение выводиться, но после нажатия на OK идет пустой экран.

Переустановка Laravel не помогла.

Домашняя страница (главная) отображается нормально, но при попытке вывести в ней `div#app` (по умолчанию в ней нет vue.js) и подключить `js/app.js` - вместо `div#app` выводит `<!---->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VueJs берет из DOM ноду, с указанной вами #app и подменяет полностью эту ноду в [момент выполнения mount](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) тем, что собственно говоря вы напишете. По ссылке обратите внимание на то что написано между событиями `beforeMount`  и `mounted`

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрел по ссылке - понял что происходит. Если смотреть по схеме выше то получается если нет опции ```template```, то vue.js берет содержимое из указанного ```el``` и по идее должен после компиляции подменить получившимся. А по факту получается он перетирает все в ноль и ничего не выводит. Честно в тупике. Думаю, что из коробки как-то по-другому должно быть.

Comment: @Plahov все верно, он должен подменить получившимся то что скомпилено. По этому вы и видите `<!---->` , это означает что все у вас работает, ну или не все :) Наверняка у вас ошибка где то мелкая, которую вы найдете и все будет работать.

Я бы рекомедовал бы вам поставить расширение для vuejs чтоб в консоли вы явно видели что у вас происходит с компонентами.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd   не забудьте только включить еще devtools в режиме разработки в самом Vue компоненте.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Я уже пробовал как-то инспектировать Vue и это расширение тоже ставил. При посещении страниц где из коробки должен работать Vue - иконка расширения не подсвечивается и выдает ```Vue.js not detected``` - но при этом содержимое страницы очищается. Верю что ошибка где-то, и будет обидно ее не найти и сдаться)) пошел уже 3 день моих попыток. Вот я не понимаю - ведь просто устанавливаю Laravel из коробки, при этом кода своего не добавляю совсем - и по итогу такие траблы )))

Comment: Как обычно рыл не в ту сторону. Запустил встроенный сервер ```php artisan serve``` и неповерите - все заработало на http://127.0.0.1:8080 Теперь моя задача настроить все на локальном домене ```.test``` так как использую локально настроенный веб сервер на Nginx, знал про ```serve```, но до последнего откладывал проверить на нем. Спасибо. Есть теперь направление мыслей.